# Socket.io in edge raises an error when connecting to server (server certificate revocation)

Tags: socket.io, microsoft-edge

My socket.io works fine on firefox, chrome, safari.

But on Edge, I got an error 12057, related with "check for server certificate revocation ".

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

When your computer unable to validate the SSL certificate it can generate this error.

You can try to refer steps below may help you to solve this error.

1) Open **Internet Explorer**.

2) Select **Tools** > **Internet Options**.

3) Click on the **Advanced** tab and scroll down to the **security** section.

4) Uncheck "**Check for server certificate revocation***" option.

5) Click "**Apply**" and "**OK**" to save the changes.

If error persist than you can also try to uncheck other option called "**Check for publisher's certificate revocation**"